# is it possible to paravirtualize 32 bit linux kernel on x64 xen hypervisor

Tags: xen

If I have a 64 bit Xen kernel (hypervisor) can I run paravirtualized x86 linux guests or does it need to be fully virtualized, just like windows?

I would like to install all small memory guests as x86 so that they use less memory than they would need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, i.e. old XenServer had 32-bit Linux as a dom0 and could run 32 and 64 bits VM (as it was used widely in production I assume that was correct approach). Only one thing that hypervisor have to do extra is translation 32 instructions to 64 bits. But what 32 bits affects is only your system memory, not your device drivers, so you can still use virtio (para-virtualized) device drivers.

More info (remember dom0 is just a VM!):
http://xenserver.org/discuss-virtualization/virtualization-blog/entry/the-reality-of-a-64-bit-dom0.html